# Mac App Store sandboxing entitlement disables when building for archiving

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

I'm trying to submit an app to the mac App Store, but every time I do, after I upload the binary with no problems I get an email saying this

"App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the    "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list. Refer to the App Sandbox page for more information on sandboxing your app."

I checked the entitlements box and sandbox box in target summary and I have an entitlements file, but when I build for archiving the box unchecks automatically and locks. Then when I build for running it unlocks and I can check it again. I've been searching everywhere for an answer but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: One thing to try:
- Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...
- Click on the Archive tab (at left) 
- Make sure that you have the correct build configuration selected (at right)

Answer (score 1):

It's late to this thread but just in case if anyone struggles - I had a similar issue and for me, it was wrong code signing certificates. Actually, I was having like Code Sign -> Release -> Any SDK (this was different certs) then what was selected during upload (automatic signing). Removed that and it was then uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

There must have been something that was set wrong, because to fix it all I did was start a new project and load all the classes, xibs, etc.